# Browser not rendering new page after http redirect

Tags: http

After performing a request the browser is not rendering the resulted page.

Request:

```
  Remote Address:[::1]:8080
    Request URL:http://localhost:8080/SPRING_JSF/pages/add.xhtml
    Request Method:POST
    Status Code:302 Found
```

Response:

```
Content-Length:0
Date:Fri, 04 Dec 2015 23:33:25 GMT
Location:http://localhost:8080/SPRING_JSF/pages/status/success.xhtml
Server:Apache-Coyote/1.1
```

The browser stays at add.xhtml page and never show success.xhtml page.